# How can you setup multiple WSGI apps on one server?

Tags: python, wsgi

I'm working on a python based server product where a user can install WSGI-based python apps on their server. I can enforce any restriction on the application structure or format to make this *easy*.

The user workflow would be:

- browse an app market, showing a list of WSGIpython apps
- select an app and choose "install"
- the app would be downloaded from a remote server to the user's server
- the http server would then have to be configured to start serving that application from the app's id, ex. a blog app with an id of "blog" at "/blog/", so all requests below /blog/ would be seen as root by the blog application.

Any suggestions on how to set something like this up?

Holler if my flow of consciousness lost you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python Paste URLMap](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#the-config-file) does this via a config file, that might give you a good start.

Comment: Oh nice, that's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. The only downside is that I'd have to restart the server after installing a new application and modifying the Paste ini config files. Is that correct? Or is there a way to do that without a server restart?

Thanks!

Comment: traditionally yeah that's how it was written.